# Many to many relationship with ASP.NET AspNetUser table gets ignored

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

One user can be a member of many projects while a project can have multiple members.

ASP.NET Identity `ApplicationUser`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Projekt")]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

My `Project`:

```
[Table("Projects")]
public class Project : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128), Display(Name = "Projektname"), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // working one-to-many relation
    [Display(Name = "Projektleiter")]
    public string LeaderID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LeaderID"), Display(Name = "Projektleiter")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    // many-to-many relation gets ignored
    [Display(Name = "Mitarbeiter")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new List<ValidationResult>();
    }
}
```

No Many-to-Many table is created. The whole relation gets ignored. But the LeaderID thing is working ...

Can somebody tell me what I am missing here? (I googled the hell out of it, I deleted the whole database multiple times, I tried everything I found, no luck ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the  ApplicationUser entity separated from whatever logic you have with the project and create another entity called Person.

```
public class Person
{
//Constuctor : always intantiate lists in ctor
public Person()
{
       Projects = new List<Project>();
}

 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string IdentityId { get; set; } //gets guid from AppUser table
 public ApplicationUser Identity { get; set; }  // navigation property
 public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
 //public int ProjectId {get; set;}//-----optional

}
```

so in projects know we do the same thing:

```
[Table("Projects")]
public class Project : IValidatableObject
{
        //Constuctor : always intantiate lists in ctor
    public Project()
    {
           Persons = new List<Person>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128), Display(Name = "Projektname"), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string PersonId { get; set; }  //nav property
    public List<Persons> Persons { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; } //context will be aware that this is fk

   [Display(Name = "Projektleiter")]
   public string LeaderID { get; set; }




    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new List<ValidationResult>();
    }
}
```

add db sets for both entities in  the dbcontext class.
Now you want to get a person with a list of projects and vice versa. For that we use the include:

```
var x = myContext.Persons.Include(x => x.Projects);
var d = x.ToList();
```

//you can use the applicationUser entity instead of person but bad things happen as the project grows.

Comment: I don't get the need for an additional table but if it's the only way ... sight ... thank you very much!

Comment: No worries yeah its just that Users in that application Users Have very sensitive information you dont want jumping around your application like security claims for password hashed. let that class handle the security and person handle w.e logic  you need for your app. Your welcome.