# Many to Many Relationship with ASPNETUSER Not creating join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create a many to many relationship between an Appointments table and the aspnetuser table (SGGUser).
I am using code first with EF 6.
My appointment object is this:

```
    public class Appointment
{   
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public SGGUser CreatorOwner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public Address LocationAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]      // Set to an ICollection to allow multiple people involved
    public virtual ICollection<SGGUser> Participants { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]      // Set to an ICollection to allow multiple services
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessService> BusinessServices { get; set; }


}
```

The SGGUser is like this:

```
    public class SGGUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<SGGUser> manager, string authenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    ...more stuff

    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }


}
```

In the appointments table, the BusinessServices object IS creating a join table as it should. Called BusinessServiceAppointments as expected.
However it doesn't create a join table for the ASPNETUSERS (SGGUSER) table and appointments.
I have tried adding this to to the context class (SGGContext):

```
    public class SGGContext : IdentityDbContext<SGGUser>
{
    public SGGContext()
        : base("SGGContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    ... more stuff

    public DbSet<BusinessService> BusinessServices { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SGGUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Appointments);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .HasMany(ap => ap.Participants);
    }


}
```

Although, I was under the impression this is only mandatory for EF core. However, every little helps I guess..

I have seen this post:[On this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857834/many-to-many-relationship-with-asp-net-aspnetuser-table-gets-ignored) but it suggests creating another table which I don't really yet see the need to do. All it says there is that 'bad things happen'? and so I am left wondering is this in fact prevented somehow by the Identity/Entity framework or have I just missed something?

Clarification: I know I need a join table. The add-migration code doesn't create it whereas the it does for the BusinessServices-Appointments relationship.

Comment: You should at least use the `HasMany/WithMany` mapping for m:n relationships, but I don't know, maybe it doesn't play nice with the configuration already present in `IdentityDbContext`. I'd prefer to leave the ASP.Net identity tables and classes untouched and extend them by your own classes, f.e. an `ApplicationUser` class in a 1:1 association with ASP.Net's `IdentityUser`.

Comment: I think I am heading that way, with a separate 'Participants' table/class, but I would like to understand what's happening... or rather isn't. Do you think the HasMany mapping I have are ok or should I use WithMany as well? Instead or?

Comment: [Instead](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will need a join table.

According to Microsoft "Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns

Comment: I think I mentioned that I need a join table in the question. Maybe I wasn't clear enough that the ef add migration code doesn't create it despite the many to many relationships that should be created by the icollection in both classes.
Thanks.

Comment: The link applies to EF-core. The question is about EF6.